# How to copy unprotected cells and then protect them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need once a day (by trigger) make data copy from unprotected cells from Table1 to Table2. Then protect copied cells. Next day copy only new unprotected cells with data and then protect them too.

My problem is - I couldn't get right range for copying to Table2.
Please give some advices

P.S. Sorry for my English

Table1 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fNshucMoC9wFjGKl9ZLvk2jw9yI2llKQ9dioGbO-F0s/edit?usp=sharing

Table2 - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11AvUWe5vu6vHNXCPfXlK1Es3JLqQh13Fy_22l-obwP0/edit?usp=sharing

```
function protect_sales()
{
  // Connect to Table 1
  var sheetIncome = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales');
  var lastRow = sheetIncome.getLastRow(); 

  var protection = sheetIncome.protect();
  var unprotected = protection.getUnprotectedRanges();


  // Connect to Table 2
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11AvUWe5vu6vHNXCPfXlK1Es3JLqQh13Fy_22l-obwP0/edit');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sales');
  var lastSRow = ss.getLastRow();

  var target_range = ss.getRange(lastSRow+1,1,lastRow,5);

  ss.insertRowAfter(lastSRow);

  // Copy Data to Table 2
  ss.getRange(2,1).setValues(unprotected);

  // Protect our Range

  var dataRange = sheetIncome.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 5)

  var protection = dataRange.protect().setDescription('protected range');

// Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
// permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
protection.addEditor(me);
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
  protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }

}
```

Comment: I think that you might misunderstand about how to use [`getUnprotectedRanges()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#getunprotectedranges). So I cannot understand about your goal. About `ss.getRange(2,1).setValues(unprotected)`, in this case, what is the value of `unprotected` you want?

Comment: You are right. I didn't understand how to use 'getUnprotectedRanges()'. I need in everyday copies (to Table2) of new added and unprotected rows and then protect them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### There are several issues with your script

1. You use `lastRow` as the row number in the target sheet, but given that you want to copy only the new rows, your row number might be smaller than the total number of rows in `sheetIncome`.

   > What you need is to define a `startRow`. An elegant solution is to save the
   >   `lastRow` of the previous script run as a [Script property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) and use
   >   it for defining the new `StartRow` for the new copy process.
2. To [set the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) of `target_range` you need to define an `original_range` in Table 1 first, without specifying either this range shall be protected:

```
  var original_range=sheetIncome.getRange(startRow,1, rowNumber,5);
  var target_range = ss.getRange(targetlastRow+1,1,rowNumber,5);
  target_range.setValues(original_range.getValues());
```

3. The protection of `dataRange` should be set at the end of the code

Here is code snippet that retrieves the new start row for every run from the `ScriptProperties`, and in case there was new data added since the last copy - it will copy the new data and update the protection of Table 1. Finally it will update the script properties with the new start row. There is also a second function to reset the script properties and start copying from the first line again. Keep in mind that if a range is protected, the protection is not valid for the spreadsheet owner, only for the other editors.

```
function protect_sales()
{
  // Connect to Table 1
  var sheetIncome = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sales'); 
  var startRow = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('start');
  if(!startRow){
    startRow=1;
  }
  var lastRow = sheetIncome.getLastRow(); 
  var rowNumber = lastRow-startRow+1;
  //if there is new data in the sheet - copy it
  if(rowNumber>0)
  {
   // Connect to Table 2
   var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TtpXaw4-vN8r-0i7WI7w9M005xxlFEkuThDI0tMTsVY/edit#gid=0');
   var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Sales');
   var targetlastRow = ss.getLastRow();
   var original_range=sheetIncome.getRange(startRow,1, rowNumber,5);
   var target_range = ss.getRange(targetlastRow+1,1,rowNumber,5);
   //following row not necessary
   //ss.insertRowAfter(lastSRow);

   // Copy Data to Table 2  
   target_range.setValues(original_range.getValues());                       

   // Protect our Range
   var dataRange = sheetIncome.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 5)
   var protection = dataRange.protect().setDescription('protected range');

   // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
   // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
   var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
   protection.addEditor(me);
   protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
   if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
   }
  }
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('start', lastRow+1);
}


function resetProperties(){
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteAllProperties();
}
```

4. If you want the script to run automatically every day, you can set up a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: I didn't know about 'PropertiesService()' class. All works great! Thank you for your time! Огромное человеческое спасибо!